# Function that returns true if http.get was successful at Guard canActivate function

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create a function that will return true if http.get was successful, otherwise return false. I was trying something like that:

```
  isOk() {
    let isOk;
    this.http.get('ip/api/isOk')
      .subscribe(x => { isOk = true; }, 
      (err) => { isOk = false; });
    return isOk;
  }
```

But it returns `undefined`. I know it's an async function so it returns a value before `http.get` finishes. How can I create a function that returns true/false after "receiving" data from a REST API?

edit:
I want to use this function at Guard `canActivate` function.
I dont know how can I construct IF statement with observable.

```
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
      let x = this.someService.isOk();
      if(...){//if isOk return true
         return true;
      }else{
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      }
  }
```

Comment: Return an observable and subscribe to where you want to use it later on.

Comment: The answer is correct, you can't return a value like with with RxJS. Can you show how you are using isOK? Depending on how you are trying to use the value, there could be a way to use the async return value of isOK.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky i want to use this function at ```canActivate``` (Guard) function.  I want to return true if function was succesfull, otherwise i want to redirect.

Comment: You should have mentioned that. Guards can use asynchronous observable that emit `boolean`.  As long as you return `Observable<boolean>` from isOK(), the guard can use that.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky can you show me how? I was trying but.. nothing works. ( i have no idea how to construct IF statement with observable)

Comment: Edit the question to include how you tried exactly to use isOK in your guard (show guard code) and then the question could be re-opened/re-evaluated.

Comment: If this is reopened I can provide an answer of using isOK with the guard.

Comment: I found solution :) Instead of `subscribe` i used `pipe(map)` and now it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to mix incompatible things: sync and async code. `http.get` is async, which means exactly following: in most cases there is no result yet at the moment when your code returns back to caller; that's why `undefined` is the only reasonable value to return.

Once you stick to async worflow, keep along endlessly. In your particular case you might want to return `Observable<boolean>` back to caller and let it `subscribe()` rather then do it yourself. Consoder `pipe()` and `map()` or `tap()` defined to be operators on the `Observable<>`. The [rxjs docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map).

Comment: I know :) But i have no idea how to fix it :) And this is actaully my question

Comment: @blady9565 as I mentioned above, do not abandon `Observable<>`. Stick to it as long as possible. Embed your sync code into async workflow represented by your `Observable`.

Comment: Ok, so how can i use this function at ```canActivate``` (Guard) ? I want to return true if function was succesfull, otherwise i want to redirect.

Comment: canActivate can return the Observable. So, in your canActive will be: `return this.http.get('ip/api/isOk')
      .subscribe(x => { your logic});`

Comment: @DanilSabirov I was trying something like that but it dont work,
I dont know how to return true (redirect works fine). In function ```canActivate``` I had something like that:

`
 return this.someService.isOk().subscribe((x) => {
      return true;    }, err =>{this.router.navigate(['/login']); });
`